# Is $\| u + v \|^2 - \| u - v \|^2= 2uv - (-2uv)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm trying to prove an equation. My professor took up the answer and I copied it down. One of the steps was this (let u and v be vectors and let || u + v || mean the norm / magnitude of u + v):

> line $1: \| u + v \|^2 - || u - v ||^2$
>
> line $2: = 2uv - (-2uv)$
>
> line $3: = 4uv$

But it doesn't look correct, even if $uv$ in line $2$ and $3$ is the dot product of $u$ and $v$, right?

Because

$$\| u + v \|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(u_i + v_i)^2$$

which is not the same thing as $2uv$ or $2\langle u , v\rangle$. Did I copy it down wrong? What could it have meant? (I'm going to go ask him during office hours but I'm trying to figure it out before I go).

Comment: There was a lot of cancellation between line 1 and line 2 that was not written down. The analogy in real numbers is $(a+b)^2 - (a-b)^2 = 2ab - (-2ab)$. Although $(a+b)^2 \not= 2ab$ and $(a-b)^2 \not= -2ab$, their differences are equal.

Comment: @UmbertoP. `\neq` is a nice and speedy command for $\neq$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor wow, how did you even manage to tell the difference!!

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor off-topic, but thanks, although I'm don't think it is worth trying to override a decades-long habit to save a single keystroke.

Comment: @JohnDoe I’m on mobile, so the MathJax markdown in the comment section isn’t automatically rendered. I just get used to reading the code and generating the image in my head ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Same thing for the MathJax in titles. Plus typography and formatting are two of my favorite things lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\|u+v\|^2=(u+v)\cdot(u+v)=u\cdot u+v\cdot u+u\cdot v+v\cdot v=\|u\|^2+2u\cdot v+\|v\|^2$$Similarly, $$\|u-v\|^2=(u-v)\cdot(u-v)=\|u\|^2-2u\cdot v+\|v\|^2$$
So it is correct.

Here, we used the symmetry of the dot product -  that $u\cdot v=v\cdot u$. We also used the distributive rule for vector fields, when expanding the quadratic-type expression.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\| u+v\|^2 -\|u-v\|^2 \\
&= \|u\|^2 + 2u^Tv + \|v\|^2-(\|u\|^2 - 2u^Tv + \|v\|^2)\\
&=2u^Tv-(-2u^Tv)
\end{align}

Your teacher cancels out $\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$ as it appears in both terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Hilbertspace, then you have $\|x\|^2=xx$ with the dot product.

Hence,
$$
\|u+v\|^2=(u+v)(u+v)=uu+uv+vu+vv = \|u\|^2+2uv+\|v\|^2
$$
and
$$
\|u-v\|^2=(u-v)(u-v)=uu-uv-vu+vv = \|u\|^2-2uv+\|v\|^2.
$$
Together you get
\begin{align}
\|u+v\|^2-\|u-v\|^2 &= (\|u\|^2+2uv+\|v\|^2)-(\|u\|^2-2uv+\|v\|^2)\\
&=2uv-(-2uv)=4uv.
\end{align}